# C++: Proper Way to Pass a Derived Class to An Abstract Class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, arduino, abstract

I'm trying to create a library to use with an Arduino to perform some web operations regardless of whether the Arduino is using an EthernetClient or a WiFiClient. Its been many, many years since I've touched anything in C++, and I think I'm messing up this whole "Pointer" vs. "Reference" vs. "Value" stuff.

I can't seem to get it right on when to use a & or a *, or whatever to make this work so that I can have a generic Client data class, which gets set to either the WiFiClient or EthernetClient value.

Can someone please help explain what I'm doing wrong, why it won't work, and possibly what the proper way is to do this so it will work?

Here's what I've got in my Header:

```
#ifndef web_h
#define web_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Client.h"
#include "WiFiClient.h"
#include "EthernetClient.h"

class web {
  public:
    web(WiFiClient* client);
    web(EthernetClient* client);
    void makeCall();
  private:
    Client& _client;
    String getRequest(String server, int port, String url);
};
#endif
```

Here's what I've got in my library cpp:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "web.h"
#include "Client.h"
#include "WiFiClient.h"
#include "EthernetClient.h"

  web::web(WiFiClient* client){
    _client = client;
  }
  web::web(EthernetClient* client){
    _client = client;
  }
  void web::makeCall(){
    String response = getRequest("www.google.com", 80, "/");
    Serial.println(response);
  }

  String web::getRequest(String server, int port, String url){
      String response = "";
      char cServer[server.length() + 1];
      server.toCharArray(cServer, server.length() + 1);

      if(_client.connect(cServer, port)){
        _client.println("GET " + url + " HTTP/1.1");
        _client.println("Host: " + server);
        _client.println();

        while (_client.available()) {
          char c = _client.read();
          response = response + c;
        }
      }
      Serial.println("inside");
      Serial.println(response);
      return response;
  }
```

And here's where I'm trying to use the library:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"
#include <web.h>

char ssid[] = "MYSID";     //  your network SSID (name) 
char pass[] = "WIRELESSPWD"; 
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
WiFiClient* client;
web webClient(*client);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    delay(10000);
  }

  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  webClient.makeCall();
}

void loop() {

}
```

The errors I'm getting include the following, depending on where I randomly put the &, *, etc, since I don't really understand what I'm doing. It never compiles:

```
wifi_test:10: error: no matching function for call to 'web::web(WiFiClient&)'


error: uninitialized reference member 'web::_client' [-fpermissive]

   web::web(WiFiClient& client){
```

Comment: If you want to understand "this whole "Pointer" vs. "Reference" vs. "Value" stuff", may I suggest you read a C++ textbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class web {
  private:
    Client& _client;
};
```

`_client` is a reference to `Client` object. Unlike a pointer, you cannot change where the reference "points to". So you have to initialize it with a value.

```
  web::web(WiFiClient* client){
    _client = client;
  }
```

In your constructor you don't initialize your `_client` variable, but you try to assign it a value. Thats is why you get an error

> error: uninitialized reference member 'web::_client'

To initialize a reference you have to use initialize list in the constructor. Here is a simplified version, that also uses just one constructor, since you don't have to have both overloads.

```
class web {
  public:
    web(Client& client);
    void makeCall();
  private:
    Client& _client;
    String getRequest(String server, int port, String url);
};

web::web(Client& client)
: _client(client)
{
}
```

Then you can create a `web` object:

```
WiFiClient client;
web webClient(client);
```

I suggest you read about references and pointers if you want to use them effectively. Otherwise you will continually have problems with them.

Comment: Thank-you, this worked! Do you know what that way of defining _client is called? web::web(Client& client) : _client(client)  <-- I'd love to read more about that.

Comment: @Doug It is called [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). Basically that is the way member variables are initialized in a constructor. If you write it the way you did in the `{ }` block, then the members are first initialized to their default values and then assigned a new value. Which does not work for references and const members.

Answer (score 0):

Your compilation error is a misuse of the '*' operator in the expression

```
web webClient(*client);
```

What you wrote means : send to the constructor a reference of the object at the address "client". If you remove the '*' char, this particular error should disappear.